# Can I use cards like Gilded Lotus and Spectral Searchlight in a colorless EDH deck?

Tags: magic-the-gathering, mtg-commander

With cards that let me add mana of any color, can they be used in a colorless commander deck? Some examples being [Spectral Searchlight](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bSpectral%20Searchlight%5d) and [Gilded Lotus](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bGilded%20Lotus%5d) in a [Kozilek, the Great Distortion](http://gatherer.wizards.com/Pages/Search/Default.aspx?name=%2b%5bKozilek%2c%20the%20Great%20Distortion%5d) deck.

I am asking because I think I remember seeing something saying I can not, but I do not remember if I am remembering correctly.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Yes, you can do that.**

When you activate the abilities of cards like Spectral Searchlight or Gilded Lotus, someone chooses a color on resolution. That color is not determined in the text itself by mana symbols, which, in addition to a card's mana cost, is the most common way of establishing a card's color identity. The other ways also don't apply:

> 903.4. The Commander variant uses color identity to determine what cards can be in a deck with a certain commander. The color identity of a card is the color or colors of any mana symbols in that card’s mana cost or rules text, plus any colors defined by its characteristic-defining abilities (see rule 604.3) or color indicator (see rule 204).

Therefore, you can use such colorless artifacts that produce a chosen color in any commander deck, including colorless ones.

Comment: I just realized i made a duplicate question